# for loop not honoring await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

So I have the following code:

```
const getHourlyData = async(size, callback) => {

  for (var i = size; i > 0; i--) {
    const candle = await internals.getData(x, y, i, (result) => {
       resultSet.push(result);
    });
  }
  callback(null, resultSet);
}
```

However the for loop is not awaiting, it always fills the array with nulls.
The getData function looks like this:

```
(x, y, i, callback) => {
    //...
    const result = pool.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        callback(results);
    });
  }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your `getData` function needs to return a promise for the `await` on it to work.

Comment: You should use `Promise.all()`.  You aren't running anything in parallel.

Comment: async/await only works with Promise, you are using callbacks

Comment: OMG you where right, I replaced my MySQL module by this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll want to build your system somewhat like this:

```
fn = async () => 1
fn2 = async () => await fn()
await fn2()
// result is 1
```

Read this and consider migrating to an async / await architecture:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99